# pyspark rdd merge multiple json file data in one rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to merge two files data into one rdd. Lets say I have two files `file1.txt` which is big json formatted file , `file2.txt` which is small csv formatted file.

`file1.txt`(json format) look like this:

```
{

{"a":1 , "b":{"ba":1 , "bb":"babc", "bc":"babc2", "d":"babc3"}, "c":"abc2"}, 

{"a":2 , "b":{"ba":2 , "bb":"babc2", "bc":"babc22", "d":"babc32"}, "c":"abc22"}

}
```

`file2.txt`(csv format) look like this:

```
key   value

xyz   xyz1

pqr   pqr1
```

Now I want my output to be rdd like this:

```
{

{"a":1 , "b":{"ba":1 , "bb":"babc", "bc":"babc2", "d":"babc3", "e":{{"key": "xyz", "value":"xyz1"},{"key": "pqr", "value":"pqr1"}}, "c":"abc2"}, 

{"a":2 , "b":{"ba":2 , "bb":"babc2", "bc":"babc22", "d":"babc32", "e":{{"key": "xyz", "value":"xyz1"},{"key": "pqr", "value":"pqr1"}}, "c":"abc22"}

}
```

What I have tried is convert `file2.txt` to json format and then perform operation like:

```
output_rdd = file1_rdd.map(lambda x: joinfunc(x, file2_rdd))
```

And then try to write `output_rdd`.

But this is giving me errors like

> cPickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error
>   occurred while calling o72.**getnewargs**. Trace: py4j.Py4JException:
>   Method **getnewargs**([]) does not exist

Any suggestion to merge this two files into one output rdd? Any suggestions will be helpful.

PS: I'm completely new to the spark.

Edit:

my joinfunc look like this:

```
def joinfunc(file1_json, file2_json):

    file1_detail = json.loads(file1_json)
    file2_detail = json.loads(file2_json)

    b_file1_detail_list = file1_detail["b"]
    append_detail =[]

    if b_file1_detail_list is not None:
        for b_file1_detail in b_file1_detail_list:
            append_detail = {"e" : file2_detail}
            b_file1_detail.append(append_detail)

    return json.dumps(dict(file1_detail))
```

Comment: Fix your `lambda` typo. Share your `joinfunc` code as well

Comment: Fixed the typo and shared the joinfunc code